# SQL Limit to number and if equal

Tags: mysql

Can I limit rows that I displaying depending on if number in row equal to show all equal rows. For example I have database that contains football statistics, and I want to display first five scorers in one season but ib some seasons some scorers on third place have same number of goals and my query doesnt display it all beacuse i limited to sql clause limit to 5. Is there a way to tell in some clause to show all rows that are equal number of goals?

```
For example list of goalscorers
Goalscorer1 7 goals
Goalscorer2 6
Goalscorer3 4
Goalscorer4 3
Goalscorer5 3
```

...and there are goalscorers 6 and 7 with also 3 goals that are not displayed

Comment: what to do if first record has two value? means two goalscorer has scored 7 goals?

Comment: Yes, good question. I just posted example, but it can also example be in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide what is the controlling factor, limit that factor in a subquery, then list the facts related to it. Here the controlling factor is the number of goals, and the related facts are the players who kicked that number of goals.

see this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26fe7/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`Player` varchar(20), `Goals` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`Player`, `Goals`)
VALUES
    ('Goalscorer1', 7),
    ('Goalscorer2', 6),
    ('Goalscorer3', 4),
    ('Goalscorer6', 3),
    ('Goalscorer7', 3),
    ('Goalscorer4', 3),
    ('Goalscorer5', 3),
    ('Goalscorer11', 1)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
    t.*
from table1 t
inner join (
          select distinct Goals from table1
          order by goals DESC
          limit 4
           ) sq on t.Goals = sq.Goals
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26fe7/3/0)**:

```
|      Player | Goals |
|-------------|-------|
| Goalscorer1 |     7 |
| Goalscorer2 |     6 |
| Goalscorer3 |     4 |
| Goalscorer6 |     3 |
| Goalscorer7 |     3 |
| Goalscorer4 |     3 |
| Goalscorer5 |     3 |
```

My re-worked version of [the pastebin query](http://pastebin.com/JFMvQzKS) referenced below:

```
SELECT
      t.*
FROM jos_playerstats t
      INNER JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                  jos_playerstats.goals
            FROM jos_playerstats
            WHERE jos_playerstats.idSeason = '".$urlID."'
            ORDER BY
                  jos_playerstats.goals DESC
            LIMIT 4
      ) sq ON t.goals = sq.goals
WHERE t.idSeason = '".$urlID."'
```

The subquery MUST ONLY contain a distinct list of goals, no other columns at all. Also: Please don't get into the habit of adding distinct into every query because performance will get worse. Only use "select distinct" when you truly need it and this should be rare and usually associated with one or very few columns.

Comment: Ahm. Thanx, but just for info, goals are different from season to season. So this equality in query 1 sq on t.Goals = sq. Goals is crucial as I see?

Comment: that query in pastebin is NOT following my advice, the subquery must focus on goals **ONLY** (nothing else) if you don't do this your results will be very strange indeed. regarding **t.Goals = sq. Goals is crucial** = YES! that is why you must ONLY have goals in the subquery.

Comment: Ok. But as you see I have one table with infos for players, second for seasons, and third is the table for statistics appearences and goals. If I put in query only goals how can I retrieve player names from other tables? Database is relational. I aboslutly agree about clause DISTINCT!

Comment: I see now your reworked code. Can I in out of subquery use my clauses for relational database left joins?

Comment: No. There is simply is no point adding left joins in that subquery, That is not what that subquery is for. If you need more joins do it BEFORE or AFTER that subquery but not inside it.